# Program that can create a collection of flipbooks in a single .exe (or .app)

Tags: ebooks

My question is similar to [this one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/73752/program-for-making-downloadable-flipbooks-and-a-library-for-them) but not identical.

I need a program that can make several flipbooks and save them together in a single .exe (or .app). When the user opens the .exe (or .app) he should get a front page (which might be called a "bookshelf") where he can select from among the different flipbooks the one that he wishes to read.